# weird error message in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm using solr and I got following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your Solr server is outputting HTML instead of the expected binary data. This usually happens because it's throwing an error and displaying an error page, and not returning  any useful information for SolrJ itself.

Check the server container log for useful information to see what the error is on the server side and fix that first.